# How to identify data source for external list?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, external-list

I'm a SharePoint noob, using SharePoint Designer 2010.

There's an External List that is pulling data from a MS SQL server.  How can I find out what database and table it's querying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Open your SharePoint designer.
- From the left menu > Select `External Content Types`.
- Click on your external content types to show its details.
- click on click `here to discover external data source and define operations`.

[image]

- you should now able to view the database and tables and type of operation (quires).

[image]

For more details check [How to: Create external content types for SQL Server in SharePoint 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee557243(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, that helped.  I was looking in Data Sources -> External Lists.